# javafx actuar en dos FXML con un solo Controller

Tags: java, javafx

Estoy intentando usar un controlador para 2 Stages diferentes y por lo que sea termina en null pointer exception no sé muy bien por qué.

El problema real es más complejo pero lo he simplificado. En resumen necesito que lo que hago en un FXML suceda en dos a la vez, así que quizás no solucionar este problema si no replantearlo de otra forma válida me puede valer.

Adjunto el código simplificado:

FXML I: Un stage con un botón que activa el método new_text y un Label que cambia con ese método.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="com.example.doublewindowtest.HelloController">
   <Button layoutX="274.0" layoutY="284.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#new_text" text="Button"/>
   <Label fx:id="label" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="-3.0" layoutY="130.0" prefHeight="114.0" prefWidth="600.0"
          text="Original text">
      <font>
         <Font size="74.0"/>
      </font>
   </Label>
</AnchorPane>
```

FXML II: Otro similar, con un botón que debería interaccionar con el Label del FXML anterior con el método onHelloButtonClick

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="com.example.doublewindowtest.HelloController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
    </padding>
    <Button text="Hello!" onAction="#onHelloButtonClick"/>
</VBox>
```

MAIN: En el main creo los 2 stages con un solo controlador.

```
package com.example.doublewindowtest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
     this.openView(stage);
     this.openSecondView();
    }

    private void openView(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("MainWindow!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void openSecondView() throws IOException {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("asd.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Second window!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER: Y aquí tengo los métodos de los 2 botones activando el Label. En el problema real no necesito que reaccione a los 2 botones, pero aquí está hecho así para poder testear con facilidad.

```
package com.example.doublewindowtest;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class HelloController {
    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    protected void onHelloButtonClick() {
        label.setText("1st panel button");
    }
    @FXML
    private void new_text(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        label.setText("2nd panel button");
    }
}
```

Es mi primera vez posteando aquí y creía que estaba en stackoverflow normal, siento haberlo posteado en inglés originalmente.
He intentado ser conciso y plantear bien el problema, siento si la duda es estúpida y muchas gracias <3

Comment: Hello, we are in Stack Overflow in Spanish please edit your question by translating it so it can be accepted and answered, also to prevent it from being closed ;)

Comment: Toda vez  que fxmloader carga fxml hace una instancia de su clase controlador por tanto y como hay una clase para dos fxml; fxmloader hace dos instancias distintas de la misma clase. En resumen, es una muy mala idea hacer que dos fxml compartan la misma clase controller

Comment: No es esencial para solucionar esto que tengan el mismo controlador. Pero tengo el mismo problema si tienen distinto controlador. He encontrado un post con una cosa similar al lo que quiero pero el problema es que yo no me puedo permitir que vuelva a abrir la ventana cada vez que le doy al botón https://genuinecoder.com/javafx-communication-between-controllers/

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es "exportar" el boton del fxml anterior para que el controller sepa que boton es exactamente, puedes hacerlo asi:

```
URL url = Paths.get("./src/main/resources/sge/proyectoerp/nombrefxmlanterior.fxml").toUri().toURL();
Pane root = FXMLLoader.load(url);
Button mybutton = (Button) root.lookup("#idboton");
```